# heroku precompile assets is it necessary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've started learning rails and I've already built two apps, one simple blog app and one store app. Now I ran into a term precompile assets when uploading to heroku, can someone explain it to me is that necessary when deploying an app to production, because i've uploaded my store app to heroku without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has an assets pipeline which consists of Sprockets and the assets helpers.

The assets pipeline will concat and minify your CSS and javascript and takes care of setting the correct paths to images and other assets. This is known as compiling the assets.

In development this is done on the fly for each request which lets you immediately see changes.

In production this would be far to slow so instead the assets should be compiled once at deploy time. [Heroku does this automatically](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) for you in a post-commit hook.

Pre-compiling is when you run `rake assets:precompile` locally and then upload or push the result to a server. This is done if you are deploying to a server without the support for the assets pipeline. For example if the production server does not have a javascript runtime which is required to run uglifier.

It adds tons of noise to the git change history and manually doing anything is a common source of user error. So pretty much it sucks and you only do it if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Assets is your `css` + `JS`. Precompile assets mean that they get joined into single `.css` and another single `.js.` file (to load it in one HTTP request). And special mechanism of minifying get applied to both these files (to make them smaller). Rails by default is setup in a way, that it uses average files in dev and compiled files in prod. You can easily change this in configs, but you shouldn't do this unless you really know what you do.

If you want you can compile this files locally running `rake assets:precompile` and then put it into git. I think that you can disable/enable precompile during heroku deploy in heroku config. But, in general, I would stick with the very defaults.

More info on asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I'm not having any issues, I have deployed both apps before I even knew about precompiling assets. That's why I'm asking, I'm not familiar with the term so I really don't want to get into it if it's not necessary for now.

Comment: It's no so crucial, but this could be easily googled. Good basic url: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html. If my answer helped you and that's what you was looking for, then pls mark it with a tick for future readers